# Custom objects per license limit for customer community plus login license

Tags: community, customer-community, licenses, experience-cloud

As per my understanding, Salesforce has 20 Custom objects per license limit for customer community login plus a license. Does anyone know how to find out the usage of custom objects in a customer community? I believe you could have objects that the community user has read access to that help drive workflows, but that the community user doesn’t see and interact with. In that case, it doesn’t count toward the limit. Similarly, if an action they complete triggers some internal flow that they don’t see or provides no direct input, it still does not count.

Can someone please confirm?

Thank you,